# Error: Unable to resolve module ./reanimated1 from *:\*\*\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js:

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, package.json

i am following this tutorial https://ritikjain1272.medium.com/making-drawer-navigator-and-a-splash-screen-on-your-react-native-app-2fb561ee17f1 and along the line, I get this Error as shown below :

```
To reload the app press "r"
To open developer menu press "d"

 BUNDLE  ./index.js

error: Error: Unable to resolve module ./reanimated1 from D:\ReactNative\HealthPanda\node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\Animated.js:

None of these files exist:
  * node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\reanimated1(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  * node_modules\react-native-reanimated\src\reanimated1\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
> 1 | import { Image, ScrollView, Text, View } from 'react-native';
  2 | import Easing from './Easing';
  3 | import AnimatedClock from './core/AnimatedClock';
  4 | import AnimatedValue from './core/AnimatedValue';
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (D:\ReactNative\HealthPanda\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:107:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (D:\ReactNative\HealthPanda\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:288:43)
    at Object.resolve (D:\ReactNative\HealthPanda\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:129:24)
    at resolve (D:\ReactNative\HealthPanda\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:33)
    at D:\ReactNative\HealthPanda\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:412:26
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at resolveDependencies (D:\ReactNative\HealthPanda\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:411:33)
    at processModule (D:\ReactNative\HealthPanda\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:140:31)
    at async addDependency (D:\ReactNative\HealthPanda\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:230:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 11)
```

My package.json is looking like this :

```
{
  "name": "HealthPanda",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.65.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.9.9",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.7.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.7.1",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.15.4",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^27.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

What do i appear to be doing wrong? Please i need help here.

Comment: Can you where and how do you import reanimated?

Comment: @MichaelBahl  did not import it, i just followed everything done in that medium.com tutorial

Comment: Did you try `react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: @MichaelBahl , no. Let me try

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).